# JavaScript SpellCheck over rides my css design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on the back end of a website and thought of installing the JavaScript SpellCheck (link here: http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/). I followed the instructions and installed the plug in with ease and it works like a charm.

The problem is that this plug in overrides my css design for the input box and text area.

I had been trying to come to a solution but could not get anywhere close. Did anyone, who installed JavaScript SpellCheck, encounter this problem and how to solve this.

**Update**

I even tried putting the css file after the plugins and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Put your css files after the plugins' css file, so that your file's css rules would have more precedence.

If you still getting overridden css rules, then use the most relative(nested - more the nesting more the precedence) selectors and `!important` if necessary.

Comment: Whats a "cloe selectors"?